# Javascript my function (written below) is undefined (when trying to draw something)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I am trying to code an in-browser snake game. I am in the very early stages of this. Right now, I am trying to display a button on the screen.

(I should mention that there are a few spots in the code where it draws a circle for no apparent reason; I put those in there as visual signals that the code is working.)

So, the issue: When I run this, it tells me that the "roundRect" function is undefined, despite the fact that I've defined it below. (There is another function, also defined at the bottom, which DOES work, so I'm pretty confident that moving the function declaration higher in the code won't solve the problem. In fact, I've tried that and it didn't work.)

I can't find any obvious problems with the function, and I'm a bit stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

I've included the javascript code below. I also have the relevant HTML and CSS, although I don't think it's part of the issue.

Here be the code:

```js
//canvas elements
var canvas = document.getElementById("SnekGamCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var px = canvas.width / 2;
var py = canvas.height / 2;

var snekColor = "#EC942D";

//classes

class clickButton {
    constructor(text, color, width, height, radius) {
        this.text = text;
        this.color = color;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    drawButton(xpos, ypos) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000"
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;

        roundRect(xpos, ypos, this.width, this.height, this.radius).stroke();
        roundRect(xpos, ypos, this.width, this.height, this.radius).fill();

        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.font = '140px san-serif';

        ctx.strokeText(this.text, xpos + 10, ypos + 10);
        ctx.fillText(this.text, xpos + 10, ypos + 10);

        draw_Ball(303, 500, 50, snekColor);
    }

    clickOnButton() {

    }

}

//buttons

var startButton = new clickButton("Start Game", "#74B5ED", 200, 50, 20);

//images
var seel = new Image();
seel.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(seel, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
seel.src = "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/086.png"

var snek_title = new Image();
snek_title.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(snek_title, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
snek_title.src = "https://globin347.com/images/Snake%20Title.png"


//begin
var gameState = 0;

function draw() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if (gameState == 0) {
        //this hasn't been implemented yet
        startMenu();
    }
    else if (gameState == 1) {
        //this hasn't been implemented yet either
        playGame();
    }
    else if (gameState == 2) {
        //ditto
        gameOver();
    }
    else {
        //something's wrong

        ctx.drawImage(seel, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.fillStyle = "#b30000";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.font = '140px san-serif';

        ctx.fillText('OH NO', 120, 120);
        ctx.strokeText('OH NO', 120, 120);

        ctx.fillText('IT BLOKE', 200, 630);
        ctx.strokeText('IT BLOKE', 200, 630);
    }

}
setInterval(draw, 10);

function startMenu() {
    ctx.drawImage(snek_title, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    /***********************************************
     * 
     * 
     * This is the problem area. When the next line, startButton.drawButton(100, 100) is commented out, the rest of the code workes normally.
     * However, if the line is not commented out, draw_Ball doesn't run, indicating that the program crashed somewhere in the button code.
     * I would like to reiterate that the button's functionality has not yet been implemented; I am only trying to get it to display.
     * 
     * 
     **********************************************/

    startButton.drawButton(100, 100);

    draw_Ball(200, 700, 50, snekColor);
}

function playGame() {

}

function gameOver() {

}

//this function was stolen from stack overflow
function showImage(width, height, image_source, alt_text) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = image_source;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt = alt_text;

}

function draw_Ball(bx, by, size, ballColor) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(bx, by, size, 0, (Math.PI * 2));
    ctx.fillStyle = ballColor;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

//This next function was taken from stack overflow

function roundRect(x, y, width, height, radius) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
    ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
    ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

```css
/* Please see documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification
for details on configuring this project to bundle and minify static web assets. */

a.navbar-brand {
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
}

/* Provide sufficient contrast against white background */
a {
  color: #0366d6;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, #b6e2dd, #2a5efe);
  border-color: #1861ac;
}

/*Link colors*/
.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1b6ec2;
  border-color: #1861ac;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

button.accept-policy {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: inherit;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
}

/* My Stuff
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/*This gives me more control over the exact dark background color*/
.dark-bg
{
    background-color: #161631;
}

.purple_gradient 
{
    /*The image used*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(#4b1ac4, #fff);

    height:100%;
    width:100%;

    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.test_box_blue
{
    /* A container with a solid color and an outline */
    background-color: #2d1eb2;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;

}

.test_box
{
    border:solid #000000;
}

#MainDiv
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

    left:0;
    top:0;

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.tundra_backround
{
    background-image: url('../images/Tundra_Fixed.png');
    width=100%;
    height=100%;
}

.white_space_box
{
    height=50 px;
}

.background_gradient
{
    background-image:linear-gradient(320deg, #fff, #96cbde);
}

.glo_button
{
    min-width: 30%;
    height: 20%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    border: 4px solid #000;
}

.big_r_button {
    background-color: #a10000;
    color: #fff;
}

.big_r_button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4e0505;
}

.big_b_button {
    background-color: #080e9f;
    color: #fff;
}

.big_b_button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #161631;
}

.big_g_button {
    background-color: #0a7727;
    color: #fff;
}

.big_g_button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #07340e;
}

.big_p_button {
    background-color: #6f1cbf;
    color: #fff;
}

.big_p_button:hover {
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #2a073e;

}

.buffer
{
    padding: 20px;
}

.big_text
{
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(12 14 39 / 0.67);
}

.fancy_text_box{
    background-image: linear-gradient(300deg, #ece1c4, #c99e69);
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 4px solid #5d3c08;
}

.simple_text_box{
    background-color: #fff;

    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.ghostly_text_box{
    background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 0.60);
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
}

.thick_border{
    border: 4px solid #000;
}

.black_and_white_gradient{
    background-image: linear-gradient(310deg, #fff, #000);
}

.red_border{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 4px solid #8f0000;
}

.model_box{
    border: 4px solid #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.image_box{
    border: 4px solid #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.chain_image_box {
    border-top: 4px solid #000;
    border-left: 4px solid #000;
    border-right: 4px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.margin_setter {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#model_display_1{

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body class="background_gradient">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark dark-bg border-bottom box_shadow mb-0">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Portfolio</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Resume">Resume</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Art3D">3D Art</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Art2D">2D Art</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Snake">Snake</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CodeExamples">Code Examples</a>
                        </li>
                        <!--
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="DataBaseHub">Database Hub</a>
    </li>
    --->
                        <!--
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Unavailable">???</a>
    </li>
        -->
                        <!--Temporary Links-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="MainDiv">
        <main role="main" class="pb-0" style="width:100%">
            <!---------------------------------->
            <div class="container-fluid purple_gradient text-center">
    <h1>Snake Game</h1>
</div>
<div class="buffer"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="fancy_text_box">
        <div class="container buffer">
            <div class="ghostly_text_box text-center">
                <h1>By the power of Javascript, here is a playable snake game.</h1>
                <div class="buffer"></div>
                <h1>Give it a moment to load.</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="buffer"></div>

            <div class="ghostly_text_box text-center">
                <canvas onload="draw()" class="simple_text_box" id="SnekGamCanvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="buffer"></div>

        <a class="button glo_button big_r_button big_text" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Back to Home</a>

        <div class="buffer"></div>
    </div>

    <!--The code be here but if you are reading this you probably already knew that-->
    <script src="~/js/Snake.js"></script>

</div>

            <!---------------------------------->
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer dark-bg text-light">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - Portfolio - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="../jsc3d-master/jsc3d/jsc3d.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your `roundRect` function isn't returning anything and you are trying to call `.stroke();` and `.fill()` on it in your class method `drawButton`

Comment: @Sandsten is that it? draw_Ball doesn't return anything either, but it doesn't cause any errors.

Comment: I have looked further into it, and I understand what you were saying. You are correct, I need to find a workaround.

Comment: You could call `fill` and `stroke` inside `roundRect`, like you are doing in the `drawBall` function. You could then pass a parameter to conditionally use `fill` and `stroke`.